# React component javascript text cleaning function is not doing it's job when I try to submit a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, formik

I have the following Formik textarea field.  I am trying to hookup a function that strips or cleans any html code, Word formatting code, or any other non-standard characters that people may paste or type in.

Here is my method to do that with:

```
const stripHtmlAndCode = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
};
```

Here is the field I want to "clean":

```
<Field
    name="car_description"
    component="textarea"
    placeholder="Please describe your vehicle as detailed as possible."
    rows="50"
    cols="500"
/>
```

And this is how I set it up:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {

    values.car_description = stripHtmlAndCode(values.car_description);
    
    axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "api/formsubmitter",
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
}}
```

But when I look in the database where I save the data, I can still see my test submissions and they still have HTML code, MS Word formatting and other test stuff I inputted into the textarea.

Honestly I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you test your function elsewhere? Are you sure it works as you expected?

Comment: I did test the function but it's like it's not even being called and I don't know why...